# Remove extra padding above large text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I have a large text at the top of my document (font size 36). Because the font is so large, Word adds extra padding/space above and below the text. This makes the page margin at the top look significantly larger than I want it to be.

How can I remove the extra padding above the text?

Answer (score 1):

When editing the header, go to DESIGN (in the header design part) and you have "header from top" to lower the space. then use the page margins to make the space bellow the header smaller

Comment: Those are page margins though. I'm talking about removing the extra padding above and below large text.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: I should clarify that I didn't mean to say "header", rather "heading", as in a large heading text (36 font size).

Comment: Then I don't understand why the page margins wouldn't help. Top margin 0 will make the large text almost at top of page. Then you can use the "before\after" spacing (in LAYOUT) to control the space under that first text

Comment: Right now, my margins are set to default (roughly an inch), but because the heading font is so large, there is extra space added above the text (even though I have space before set to 0). For example, if you try adding text at 72 point font, you'll notice there is extra space above the letters when you highlight the text. That's what I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: Set page margin top to 0. Then use "space before" for the space before the text that comes AFTER the heading text - to push it up closer.

Comment: That would work, but it seems dirty and imprecise. Is there really no way to just remove the extra space above the text?

Answer (score 1):

*First, extra padding before large text at the top of a page is somewhat of a publishing norm as far as I know. That said...*

### This is likely paragraph formatting.

Select the text and right-click to get to the paragraph formatting and change the space-before setting.

If you want a more detailed answer, save a document with the problem on OneDrive or DropBox and include a view link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to change the layout (i.e. make layout portrait instead). Create a block for sizing that you want your letters/word but it should be sideways (horizontal). Create a text block and put your letters/words inside the box and turn it sideways also inside the box. You can move this text box anywhere you want taking away the space at the top so it is actually centered in the block without having the big space above the letters/words. Hope this makes sense.